# Abusive notation with disjoint union

Tags: general-topology

Is it correct to say that the disjoint union, which formally (according to Wikipedia, at least) is a *set of pairs* where the first entry is an “index” that the second entry was drawn from a particular set and not another, is often treated as though it was just a regular union, but is used to emphasise that the sets we are taking the union of are disjoint?

Take this Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

In the Examples section, I believe that the preimage of $U$ under $r$ should be a union (of disjoint objects) rather than a disjoint union, since $r$ is not defined on a set of *pairs*. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes yes, correct.

Comment: Different authors use symbols in different ways.  It is not uncommon for $A\sqcup B$ to represent the union of $A$ and $B$ where the usage of $\sqcup$ instead of $\cup$ is merely there to emphasize the fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint rather than wanting the elements in $A\sqcup B$ to be ordered pairs either of the form $(a,0)$ or $(b,1)$.

Comment: Even if it *were* the case that we were to have the elements be ordered pairs... what does that really change?  The set $\Bbb R$ has much of the same properties as the set $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$ and there is an obvious bijection, isomorphism, homomorphism, and whatever other "morphisms" you care to discuss... so much so to the point that these might as well be treated "the same" much like how we can talk about the integer "1" and the real number "1" and the complex number "1" as effectively being the "same number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is notational issue. You correctly argue that the disjoint union of an indexed family of sets $X_\alpha$ is usually defined as

$$\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha\times \{\alpha\} = \{(x, \alpha) \in \left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha \right) \times A \mid x \in X_\alpha \} .$$
But as JMoravitz comments, some authors write $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ instead of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ if the $X_\alpha$ *are known to be pairwise disjoint*. Doing so the equation $D = \bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ means that

1. $D$ is the ordinary union of the sets $X_\alpha$.
2. The $X_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint.

This is okay if the meaning of $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A}$ is clear from the context, but the serious danger is that it might be confused with the disjoint of not necessarily pairwise disjoint $X_\alpha$.

In my opinion one should not use $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A}$ for the ordinary union of pairwise disjoint sets. If it is really regarded as useful in some cases, then one should introduce a new symbol, for example $\dot \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}$.